# set value on check unchecked in jquery function

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery function on click on check i am set value in text box but     how do i remove set value from checkbox when user uncheck so how can i set     value zero on text box when user unchecked on checkbox.

```
    function tdsCount()
{
  var tdslabour = $('#labour').val() != '' ? $('#labour').val() : 0;
  var tdsfor    = $('.tds').val();
  var fianltdslabour = 0;

  if($('.tds').attr('checked', true))
  {
    fianltdslabour = (parseFloat(tdslabour)) * 1 /100;
  }
  else if($('.tds').attr('checked',false))
  {
    $('.tdsla').val(0);
  }
  $('.tdsla').val(fianltdslabour);
}

<td><input type="checkbox" name="tdsbb"  class="tds" value="Y" onClick="tdsCount();">
   TDS<input type="text"  name="tdsaa" class="tdsla" value="{$tds}"></td>
```

Comment: where's your check uncheck function...?

Comment: please inset html code .here we dont understand which is text box and which is text box

Comment: what  should i write code in else condition?